# The function setTimezone changes the timezone but not the date

Tags: php

I am trying to change the TimeZone of my date from *Europe/Berlin* to *UTC* before storing in it into the DB.

When I use the *setTimezone()* method of the *DateTime* object, it changes the timezone property but not the date itself.

Example code :

```
$dt = new \DateTime();
var_dump($dt);

$dt->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Indian/Comoro'));
var_dump($dt);

$dt->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
var_dump($dt);
```

And the result :

```
object(DateTime)#1479 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-02-18 14:12:37.521579" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" }

object(DateTime)#1479 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-02-18 14:12:37.521579" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Indian/Comoro" }

object(DateTime)#1479 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-02-18 14:12:37.521579" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }
```

Berlin is UTC+1 and Comoro is UTC+3, but the date doesn't change.

I'm working with **Symfony 4** on **Vagrant**.
This test is made inside of a controller
Is it possible that my Timezones are all set to +00 ?
What kind of tests could I implement to find the cause of this problem ?

**UPDATE**
This returns me an offset of 0 in my controller.
It returns 3600 with php CLI.

```
$tz = new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');
var_dump($tz->getOffset(new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'))));
```

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](https://3v4l.org/eb848). What's your PHP version and platform? Does it happen too in a standalone script?

Comment: I use PHP 7.3.2. I tried in php interactive mode and it didn't work. The problem was solved in the PHP CLI after updating tzdata package, but still doesn't working in my controller.

Comment: Read here for more info http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php#94784

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was from the tzdata package which worked well after updating.
I had to restart apache to make it work in my app.

Comment: Despite what other answer so far claim, the code in the question is fine and should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp value represented by the DateTime object is not modified when you set the timezone using this method.  Only the timezone, and thus the resulting display formatting, is affected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming the date is set to Europe/Berlin timezone by default):

```
$dt = new \DateTime();
```

Pass through the timezone UTC:

```
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone('UTC');
```

we then need to get the offset.

```
$offset = $timezone->getOffset($dt);
```

lastly, modify the date using the offset:

```
$dt->modify($offset . 'seconds');
```

Comment: An offset of 0 is returned, my DateTime is in UTC and I set the TimeZone to Europe/Berlin

Comment: @ga3tan try passing UTC through then, as the code above is from based of UTC -> Europe/Berlin. So reverse it. I will update code above.